Wedge product discrepancies
Please forgive in advance this basilar and naive question.
Let $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2$ be differential one forms on a space $X$ of finite dimension.
Clearly $p_1 \wedge q_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge q_2$ is a $4$-form on $X$.
Thanks to wedge product antisymmetry we get
$$p_1 \wedge q_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge q_2 = p_2 \wedge q_2 \wedge p_1 \wedge q_1$$.
Now define $\omega = p_1 \wedge q_1$ and $\eta = p_2 \wedge q_2$.
We know that generally $\omega \wedge \eta = - \eta \wedge \omega$. But this means
$$p_1 \wedge q_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge q_2 = - p_2 \wedge q_2 \wedge p_1 \wedge q_1$$
How to reconcile the two results? And if they're not reconcilable, why?

$\omega\wedge\eta=-\eta\wedge\omega$ may not be true in general. As you observe, when $\omega$ and $\eta$ are 2-forms, $\omega\wedge\eta=\eta\wedge\omega$.

$\omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{kl} \eta \wedge \omega$, where $k$ and $l$ are the orders of $\omega$ and $\eta$, respectively.
